# Paginate Return only Pagination without data Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pagination

I am trying to paginate my data using laravel paginate.So that's how i am doing that i have store model that have one to many relation with coupon model.

```
class Store extends Model
{

    protected $fillable =['id','name','heading_1','url','slug','image','status','total_coupon_used_times'];


    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'store_categories', 'category_id', 'store_id');
    }
    public function coupons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Coupon');
    }
}
```

This is my coupon model that have inverse of one to many relation.

```
class Coupon extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['id','name','description','status','coupon_type','coupon_status','coupon_code','discount_amount','coupon_url','coupon_used_times','slug','store_id'];


    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }
}
```

Further when i had tried to query my store model with coupons using paginate. I was successfully in doing so.

Here is my store controller in which i had done same thing successfully.

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('get')) {
            $name=$request->input('letter');
            $category=$request->input('category');
            $categories=Category::all();
            if($name==null || $category==null){
                $stores = Store::with('coupons')->paginate(15);
                $storesWithCount=$this->countCoupons($stores);

                return view('stores', ['stores' => $storesWithCount,'search'=>false,'categories'=>$categories]);
            }else {
                $stores=Store::has('categories')->where('name', 'LIKE', "$name%")->get();
                $storesWithCount=$this->countCoupons($stores);
                return view('stores', ['stores' => $storesWithCount,'search'=>true,'categories'=>$categories]);
            }

        }else{
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
    }
}
```

But i had tried to do samething with my coupon model in my coupon controller it gives me only pagination without data.

```
class CouponController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('get')){
            $coupons=Coupon::with('store')->paginate();

            return view('coupons',['coupons'=>$coupons]);

        }else{
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

    }
}
```

here is the image of data which its return to view 
[image]

Coupon controller also return data if replace paginate with get().

```
public function index(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('get')){
            $coupons=Coupon::with('store')->paginate();
            die($coupons);
            return view('coupons',['coupons'=>$coupons]);

        }else{
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

    }
```

So if anyone has idea that what i am doing wrong let me know.
Thanks Best Regards.

Comment: Did you try filling in the amount you want to view in your paginate like so : `$coupons=Coupon::with('store')->paginate(30);` ?

Comment: yes i had tried with it

Answer (score 0):

try giving a number

```
if($request->isMethod('get')){
        $coupons=Coupon::with('store')->paginate(10);

        return view('coupons',['coupons'=>$coupons]);

    }else{
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
```